# Parametric equation for developing of circle

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

I'm working on a gear outline that uses involute of a circle.
I want to find the intersection (I) between an involute (D) of radius r1 and a circle (C) of radius r2 (where u,v in ]0;pi/2[) :

```
D : xi = r1 * (cos(u) + u*sin(u))
    yi = r1 * (sin(u) - u*cos(u))

C : xi = r2 * cos(v)
    yi = r2 * sin(v)
```

Thus the equation to calculate I coordinates is:

```
r1 * (cos(u) + u*sin(u)) = r2 * cos(v)
r1 * (sin(u) - u*cos(u)) = r2 * sin(v)
```

Help is wanted to resolve this equation.

Comment: Is $t$ a known constant?

Comment: My own guess is that $t=u$. In any case, we need to know.

Comment: Instead of "developing of a circle" (I think you translate from a latin language) use the name  "circle involute"(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleInvolute.html)

Comment: Question updated with "involute" and `t=u` @Harald_Hanche-Olsen @JeanMarie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for the parametric equations of the involute:

> $x_i = r_1 * (\cos(u) + u*\sin(u))$
>
> $y_i = r_1 * (\sin(u) - u*\cos(u))$

But for the circle, don't use parametric equations ; express plainly that you are looking for the (unique) point of the evolute that is at distance $r_2$ from $0$, i.e., constraint $x_i^2+y_i^2=r_2^2$

$$r_1^2 [(\cos(u) + u*\sin(u))^2+ (\sin(u) - u*\cos(u))^2]=r_2^2$$

Dividing by $r_1^2$, setting $r:=r_2/r_1$ and expanding, one obtains the following result (using $\sin^2u+\cos^2u=1$...):

$$1+u^2=r^2 \ \ \implies \ \ u=\sqrt{r^2 - 1} \ \ \ \ \ ( \text{we assume} \ 1 \leq \ r \ \ \iff \ \ r_1 \leq r_2 )$$

(because $u >0$). It suffices now to plug this value of $u$ into the equations of the involute to get the intersection point, if any (because the other condition $u < \pi/2$ has to be fulfilled).

Comment: I think it's more $$1+u^2=r^2 \ \ \implies \ \ u=\sqrt{r^2 - 1} \ \ \ \ \ ( \text{we assume} \ 1 \leq \ r \ \ \iff \ \ r_1 \leq r_2 ) $$ But the calculation is great and usefull!

Comment: You are perfectly right ! Corrected. Thanks !